# Why can't I accept/mark the answer?

Tags: discussion

I had asked a question here in this website, then received some comments as suggestion. Initially I thought it wasn't the solution but then I tried it and I realized it was the solution. 'Help' section says not to post a comment to thank to the responder, but I wanted to go and accept his/her answer as solution to guide other users might have similar problems. I'm following the FAQ instructions, but I don't have even the described icon to click to accept the answer. Here is the link of the thread;

[How to get a list of keyboard shortcuts that I use for my macros?](https://superuser.com/questions/1472096/how-to-get-a-list-of-keyboard-shortcuts-that-i-use-for-my-macros?noredirect=1#comment2221052_1472096)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm following the FAQ instructions, but I don't have even the described icon to click to accept the answer.

They didn’t post an answer. They simply left some comments for you. Ask them to post the comment that solved your issue as an answer and then you can check it off as such.

Comment: @Ali, it looks like that comment was converted to an answer. But to add to this answer, sometimes the commenter doesn't post an answer (they might be an infrequent visitor, or for some reason don't want to post the answer). If you ask them to post an answer and within a reasonable time they don't do it, you can post the answer yourself and accept your own answer (need to wait 2 days after posting the question to accept your own answer; no time requirement for accepting other people's answers). It's generally good form in that case to acknowledge the person who suggested it in the comment.